# Need help to build kuksa databroker for aarch64 or for arm64

Tags: arm, grpc, arm64, kuka-krl

I m using ubuntu 22 version x86
I m try to build kuksa_databroker
tools intsalled for this :-
rust newest version
cargo
rustup

then I m trying to run command
cargo build --target x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu --examples --bins --release
its working fine

but when i try to build for aarch64 or for arm64 it provide error
cargo build --target aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu  --examples --bins --release

for arm i m using armv7-unknown-linux-gnueabi
it providing error

Compiling databroker-examples v0.4.1 (/home/ubuntu/kuksa_4/kuksa.val/kuksa_databroker/databroker-examples)
Compiling databroker v0.4.1 (/home/ubuntu/kuksa_4/kuksa.val/kuksa_databroker/databroker)
Compiling databroker-cli v0.4.1 (/home/ubuntu/kuksa_4/kuksa.val/kuksa_databroker/databroker-cli)
error: linking with `cc` failed: exit status: 1

Compiling databroker-examples v0.4.1 (/home/ubuntu/kuksa_4/kuksa.val/kuksa_databroker/databroker-examples)
Compiling databroker v0.4.1 (/home/ubuntu/kuksa_4/kuksa.val/kuksa_databroker/databroker)
Compiling databroker-cli v0.4.1 (/home/ubuntu/kuksa_4/kuksa.val/kuksa_databroker/databroker-cli)
error: linking with `cc` failed: exit status: 1
|
= note: LC_ALL="C" PATH="/home/ubuntu/.rustup/toolchains/stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/rustlib/x86_64-unknown-li>
= note: /usr/bin/ld: /home/ubuntu/kuksa_4/kuksa.val/target/aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/examples/perf_subscriber->
/usr/bin/ld: /home/ubuntu/kuksa_4/kuksa.val/target/aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/examples/perf_subscriber->
/usr/bin/ld: /home/ubuntu/kuksa_4/kuksa.val/target/aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/examples/perf_subscriber->
/usr/bin/ld: /home/ubuntu/kuksa_4/kuksa.val/target/aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/examples/perf_subscriber->
/usr/bin/ld: /home/ubuntu/kuksa_4/kuksa.val/target/aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/examples/perf_subscriber->
/usr/bin/ld: /home/ubuntu/kuksa_4/kuksa.val/target/aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/examples/perf_subscriber->
/usr/bin/ld: /home/ubuntu/kuksa_4/kuksa.val/target/aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/examples/perf_subscriber->
/usr/bin/ld: /home/ubuntu/kuksa_4/kuksa.val/target/aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/examples/perf_subscriber->
/usr/bin/ld: /home/ubuntu/kuksa_4/kuksa.val/target/aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/examples/perf_subscriber->
/usr/bin/ld: /home/ubuntu/kuksa_4/kuksa.val/target/aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/examples/perf_subscriber->
/usr/bin/ld: /home/ubuntu/kuksa_4/kuksa.val/target/aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/examples/perf_subscriber->
/usr/bin/ld: /home/ubuntu/kuksa_4/kuksa.val/target/aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/examples/perf_subscriber->
/usr/bin/ld: /home/ubuntu/kuksa_4/kuksa.val/target/aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/examples/perf_subscriber->
/usr/bin/ld: /home/ubuntu/kuksa_4/kuksa.val/target/aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/examples/perf_subscriber->
/usr/bin/ld: /home/ubuntu/kuksa_4/kuksa.val/target/aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/examples/perf_subscriber->
/usr/bin/ld: /home/ubuntu/kuksa_4/kuksa.val/target/aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/examples/perf_subscriber->
/usr/bin/ld: /home/ubuntu/kuksa_4/kuksa.val/target/aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/examples/perf_subscriber->
/usr/bin/ld: /home/ubuntu/kuksa_4/kuksa.val/target/aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/examples/perf_subscriber->
/usr/bin/ld: /home/ubuntu/kuksa_4/kuksa.val/target/aarch64-unknown-linux-gnu/release/examples/perf_subscriber->
/usr/bin/ld: /

....
this kind of error came

[kuksa-databroker](https://github.com/eclipse/kuksa.val/tree/master/kuksa_databroker)
[kuksa.val](https://github.com/eclipse/kuksa.val)

need suggestion on it how to resolve

[kuksa-databroker](https://github.com/eclipse/kuksa.val/tree/master/kuksa_databroker)
[kuksa.val](https://github.com/eclipse/kuksa.val)

need suggestion on it how to resolve

Answer (score 0):

This error was thrown by linker, when you start a cross-compilation but not specify the linker for that.
To solve this error, check this file:

```
~/.cargo/config.toml
```

and then add the specific linker for the target that you are trying to build for. For example:

```
[target.armv7-unknown-linux-gnueabihf]
linker = "arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc"
```